# Trying to determine the "height" of organisms Using Python Code

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to take a text file with a list in it take the input values and ranking them in "Height" meaning that any animal that eats only producer has height 1.

I think I have a low understanding of how to tackle this problem which is:

1. setting up the heights of all organisms including the producers to 0
2. mark that something has changed
3. while something has changed...

   1. mark that nothing has changed
   2. for each animal, `a`, in the food web

      1. for each animal, `p`, that `a` preys on

         1. if the height of a is less than or equal to the height of p, set the height of a to the height and mark that something has changed

Any help is much appreciated. I hope I haven't been too wordy or confused my message

```
foodweb = {}

with open('AquaticFoodWeb.txt') as input:
    for line in input:
        animal, prey = line.strip().split(' eats ')
        foodweb.setdefault(animal, []).append(prey)

print ("Predators and Prey:")

for animal, prey in sorted(foodweb.items()):
    if len(prey) > 1:
        print ("{} eats {} and {}".format(animal, ", ".join(prey[:-1]),     prey[-1]))
    else:
        print ("{} eats {}".format(animal, ", ".join(prey)))

#Apex

values = [item.strip() for sub in foodweb.values() for item in sub]
for apex in foodweb.keys():
    if apex.strip() not in values:
        print("Apex Predators: ", apex)
```

This is the text file input:

```
Bird eats Prawn
Bird eats Mussels
Bird eats Crab
Bird eats Limpets
Bird eats Whelk
Crab eats Mussels
Crab eats Limpets
Fish eats Prawn
Limpets eats Seaweed
Lobster eats Crab
Lobster eats Mussels
Lobster eats Limpets
Lobster eats Whelk
Mussels eats Phytoplankton
Mussels eats Zooplankton
Prawn eats Zooplankton
Whelk eats Limpets
Whelk eats Mussels
Zooplankton eats Phytoplankton
```

The output wanted:

```
 Heights:
  Bird: 4
  Crab: 3
  Fish: 3
  Limpets: 1
  Lobster: 4
  Mussels: 2
  Phytoplankton: 0
  Prawn: 2
  Seaweed: 0
  Whelk: 3
  Zooplankton: 1
```

Comment: Show us your attempt, some code may be.

Comment: Some code to just read the file would be a good start, there should be many examples on StackOverflow.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I have written the code I have in this program, however this is where I'm stuck with the Height. I have no background knowledge with the appropriate height code thus I'm having difficulty showing you something I don't have

Comment: Have you tried reading your data into a tree and then performing a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is not a homework, the below code can solve your problem.

```
animals=[]
preys=[]

with open('AquaticFoodWeb.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        animals.append(line.split()[0])
        preys.append(line.split()[-1])

height = {}

length = len(preys)
rank = 0
while preys != [None]*length:
    for index,(animal,prey) in enumerate(zip(animals,preys)):
        if prey not in animals:
            try:
                if height[prey] < rank:
                    height[prey] = rank
            except KeyError:
                height[prey] = 0

            height[animal] = height[prey] + 1

            preys[index] = None
            animals[index] = None
    rank += 1

print sorted(height.items(),key = lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[('Lobster', 4), ('Bird', 4), ('Fish', 3), ('Whelk', 3), ('Crab', 3),('Mussels', 2), 
('Prawn', 2), ('Zooplankton', 1), ('Limpets', 1),('Phytoplankton', 0), ('Seaweed', 0)]
```

Comment: No, not homework, but data analysis in presentable format. However, in order to get the output without the brackets (round and square), should I be using a print format list?

Comment: actually it was a dictionary, as dictionary can't be sorted, i made it a list of tuple. You can print the dictionary (key ,value) with some formatting

Answer (score 2):

That's not a bad start. My analysis of what it needs:

For each organism, the height is one more than the maximum height of
organisms it eats. Seaweed and Phytoplankton are 0 because they don't
eat anything. Zooplankton and Limpets are 1 because they eat only
level-0 organisms.

So, start with a mapping from organisms to a list of what they eat. You
have that, except you need to add a line that will also capture the
lowest-level organisms that don't eat anything:

```
with open('AquaticFoodWeb.txt') as input:
    for line in input:
        animal, prey = line.strip().split(' eats ')
        foodweb.setdefault(animal, []).append(prey)
        foodweb.setdefault(prey, [])  # new line of code
```

For the rest, just an outline, because this sounds like homework and I
would not deprive you of your education.

The next step is to convert `foodweb` to another mapping, from organisms
to heights. Here I would sort by length of value, to put the level-0
organisms on top, then make one or more passes. For each key, if the
heights of all prey organisms are known, assign the key the maximum
height plus one, then remove this key from `foodweb`.

Level-0 organisms are added right away because they have no prey. Then
we catch the things that eat them. It will probably take more than one
pass, but eventually `foodweb` will be empty and the output will be
full.